# mlpack: Lasso regression that takes in pointer to function

Tags: c++, machine-learning, signal-processing, mlpack

from
http://www.mlpack.org/doxygen.php?doc=classmlpack_1_1regression_1_1LARS.html

I'm trying to use 
void mlpack::regression::LARS::Regress 
but the function itself only takes in some &gramMatrix as input. If I want to pass in function to compute some sum R_i * X_i, I'm stuck because it only takes in pointer to matrix. Any idea on how to get around this ? ( the beta is constantly updating within the optimization function void mlpack::regression::LARS::Regress, and beta is neeeded to compute sum R_i * X_i ).

Any suggestion to other C++ ml library would also be madly helpful. 
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you've read the documentation completely?  `Regress()` takes in a reference to a matrix, not a pointer.  I don't understand the rest of your question, or why it matters whether a pointer, value, or reference is used by `Regress()`.

Comment: so I want to pass in function to do some computation instead of passing a matrix. Do you know if there's any workaround that maybe I can overwrite the function?